# Typescript error TS2532 for guarded Map access

Tags: typescript

Typescript marks as TS2532 error both `conn.get(aa)` below. But both accesses are guarded by `if(conn.has(aa))` so I deduce the `get` is valid and not undefined.

```
const conn: Map<string, {from: string[]; to: string[]}> = new Map();
const aa = "aa";
if(conn.has(aa)) conn.get(aa).to.push("bb");

conn.set("aa", {from: [], to: []});
if(conn.has(aa)) conn.get(aa).to.push("bb");
```

Even if I test for existence like this:

```
if(conn.has(aa) && conn.get(aa)) conn.get(aa).to.push("bb");
```

typescript complains on `conn.get(aa)`. Where is the hidden problem I cannot see? Thanks!

Comment: Well, without the finesse of checking with `has(key)` this seems to comply with typescript control flow: `const getaa = conn.get(aa); if(getaa) getaa.to.push("bb");` It is an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `conn.has(aa)` is a javascript function and `conn.get(aa)` **type** is a TypeScript feature. Therfore you cannot use **has** to ensure **get** will return not **undefined** value.

You should assert the get after the if, that would make no change in the bundle but tell the compiler that the value was checked `(conn.get(aa)!).to`

Comment: Now understand! I was thinking of some sort of connection between has and get. So the friendly '!' or checking directly the get are the solution. Thanks!